# writing equation: error ! Display math should end with $$

Tags: math-mode

I have a problem with writing this equation that displays the error in the object. I think I didn't understand well the syntax of writing equation.

```
\[$\Delta$V\textsubscript{pgm} \frac{q$\Delta$V\textsubscript{T}}{C\textsubscript{pp}} \]
```

Comment: You used `$` inside of the maths environment started with `\[`. Drop all those `$`s in your equation, they are causing the problems.

Answer (score 4):

As noted in my comment, you shouldn't use `$` inside of a displayed maths environment. `$` starts and ends inline maths. Also you shouldn't use `\textsubscript` inside of math mode as this is for text mode (as the name suggests). Subscript can be added with `_` in math mode. For indices which should be printed upright because they are abbreviations or full words, you should use `\text` provided by `amsmath`. Your whole equation then becomes:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
  \Delta V_{\mathrm{pgm}} \frac{q\Delta V_T}{C_{\mathrm{pp}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** As noted by @egreg in the comments, the usage of `\text` depends on the context. If `pgm` and `pp` are textual objects then `\text` is correct in the above. If they are not textual then one should use `\mathrm` instead.

Comment: `\mathrm{pgm}` maybe?

Comment: @egreg depends on context that I don't know. If it's something textual then `\text` else `\mathrm`.

Comment: @Skillmon true but in 99.99% of the time a superscript should be mathrm